# Building and running C++ program in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw

I am trying to revise my C++ coding skills, last time I played with C++ was about a year ago, then I was using CodeBlocks but I heard Eclipse does support C++ and I wanted to try it in Eclipse basically because its my favourite, i am using `Eclipse 4.4 mars 1`, I downloaded the`C++ plugin` and the `MwinGW Compiler`, but here is the thing, every time I try running my code it gives me an error to say `launch failed. Binary not found`, according to what I know it means I did not build my project, so I give another try, this time I Hold  `Ctrl + B` to compile and it does compile yet it gives me the same error again (sometimes it tells me `Nothing to build for project_name`), I try looking up google and youtube but all tutorials but, with them they simply build the code and run it, but for me when I build the code and try running it, a `run as` window appears with two option; `C/C++ Container Application` and `Local C/C++ Application`, wether or not I choose A or B it still bring the same error, now I am kind of confused, what is it I have to do to make it work, Here are some screenshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps not what you wanted to hear, but: there are certainly better IDEs for C++ coding that Eclipse (I might be biased). Go and get something like Visual Studio Community Edition (it's free)

Comment: Learn the language without an IDE first. Just use a compiler.

Comment: @Marged my program is to work with Java, but Java and Visual studio dont    really work together, besides eclipse has some great plugins for Java

Comment: You didn't mention that you need to interface Java and C++. Depending on how you intend to connect the two you could still have separate projects in Eclipse and VS. If you use JNA or JNI you gain nothing when you have the C++ source in the same Eclipse workspace. Mingw might introduce new problems in contrast to plain VS.

Comment: thank you, I think VB will do then